# Proving that a space is complete

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

There is something that bugs me about the proof I've been shown that $C(\Omega)$ (the space of continuos function on $\Omega$, a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$) with the $\sup$ norm is complete.

Basically they say: let $\{u_m\} \in C(\Omega)$ be cauchy; $||u_n - u_m|| \to 0$.
Let $u$ be the function they converge to; with some clever inequalities we show that $u$ is continuos, hence $u \in C(\Omega)$ and we're happy.

But I don't know that the $\{u_m\}$ are converging to anything! Above they assumed that there is a "limit", $u$, to which the functions converge to, which seems weird to me because it comes out of nowhere.I don't know what kind of object $u$ is, if it exists at all!

Now I was trying to prove that the space $\mathcal L(H_1, H_2)$ (the space of all bounded linear operators from the hilbert space $H_1$ to $H_2$) is complete with the norm $$||L|| = \sup_{||x||_{H_1}=1} ||Lx||_{H_2}$$

But I don't know where to start because I don't think I can say "Let $L$ be the linear operator the cauchy sequence $\{L_m\}$ is converging to.. "

Comment: @DavidMitra I think we need $\Omega$ to be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$.. I'll edit :)

Comment: Because the range of the functions is complete, the Cauchy sequences of functions are pointwise covergent, so they have a limit in this sense. But this limit is not *a priori* a limit in the topological sense: one has to prove that it is in the space, and that the sequence really converges to it.

Comment: In both cases you let $u$ and $L$ be the pointwise limit, and then you must prove that it lies in the space and that the Cauchy sequence actually converges to it.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Ah, I see.. So basically we always take the pointwise limit (which we know exists thanks to the fact that our underlying spaces are complete and the cauchyness of our $\{L_n\}$ implies the cauchyness of $\{L_n(x)\}$ for every $x$) and show that the pointwise limit is in the space we care about. Cool, thanks. And finally, is cauchyness a word?

Comment: Yeah, that is the general idea. :-) As for your additional question: cauchyness is a word in the sense that it is [a sequence of letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Words_over_an_alphabet), but on the other hand it is not a word in the sense that it is not in the dictionary. Still, I think we all know what you mean, so it's fine to use it here. :-) Better not use it in a thesis or a publication though.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn : I used to think like you, then I made a quick google search : it seems it's used, even in books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the $u_m$ converges to a function, because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Indeed, for every $x \in \Omega$, you have

$$| u_n(x) - u_m(x) | \leq \| u_n - u_m\|_\infty \to 0$$

So $u_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, converges.

The function $u\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is then defined by :

$$u(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n (x)$$

---

For your second question, you can define the operator L by :

$$L(x) = \lim_{n\to + \infty} L_n(x)$$

This limit exist, because you can show that $(L_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence, and by completness of $H_2$, you get the result.

It's a Cauchy sequence, because for $x\in H_1$,

$$\| L_n(x) - L_m(x) \|_{H_2} \leq \|x\|_{H_1} \| L_n-L_m\|_{\mathcal{L}(H_1,H_2)} \to 0$$

You need then to show that it's linear, but it's trivial :

$$L(x+\lambda y) = \lim_{n\to + \infty} L_n(x+\lambda y) = \lim_{n\to + \infty} L_n(x) + \lambda  L_n(y) = L(x) +  \lambda L(y)$$

Then you need to prove that it's continuous...

Comment: Okay, if we know $\mathbb R$ is complete then we call $u(x)$ the pointwise limit of our sequence and show that is continuos. But in a more abstract case? Like in the example I mentioned?

Comment: @Ant : I added the case of the continuous linear operator between Hilbert spaces

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I kinda figure it out in the meanwhile but you've been very helpful ;-) I needed a nudge in the right direction :D

Answer (score 1):

The thing about $C(\Omega)$ works because $\mathbb R$ is complete: If $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C(\Omega)$ then the definition of the metric shows that for every $x\in\Omega$ the sequence $(f_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence of reals. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete there exists a real number $y$ such that $f_n(x)\to y$; we define $f(x)=y$ and proceed.

The completeness of $\mathcal L(H_1,H_2)$ works exactly the same, using the fact that $H_2$ is complete.

Ok, not *exactly* the same, because the norm is not the sup over all of $H_1$. But it's easy to show that if $(T_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal L(H_1,H_2)$ and $x\in H_1$ then $(T_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H_2$.